# Is there any way to run np.where on multiple values rather than just one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, image-processing

I'm wondering if I have an image in a numpy array, say 250x250x3 (3 channels), is it possible to use np.where to quickly find out if any of the 250x250 arrays of size 3 are equal to [143, 255, 0] or another color represented by rgb and get a 250x250 bool array?

When I try it in code with a 4x4x3, I get a 3x3 array as a result and I'm not totally sure where that shape is coming from.

```
import numpy as np

test = np.arange(4,52).reshape(4,4,3)
print(np.where(test == [4,5,6]))

-------------------------------------------

Result:

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2]])


What I'm trying to get:

array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You don't need `np.where` (or anything particularly complicated) at all. You can just make use of the power of boolean arrays:

```
print(np.all(test == [4,5,6], axis=-1).astype(int))
# output:
#     [[1 0 0 0]
#      [0 0 0 0]
#      [0 0 0 0]
#      [0 0 0 0]]
```

An equivalent alternative would be to use `logical_and`:

```
print(np.logical_and.reduce(test == [4,5,6], axis=-1).astype(int))
# output:
#     [[1 0 0 0]
#      [0 0 0 0]
#      [0 0 0 0]
#      [0 0 0 0]]
```

## Heavy duty test

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# the subarray we'll search for
pattern = [143, 255, 0]

# generate a random test array
arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(255,255,3))

# insert the pattern array at ~10000 random indices
ix = np.unique(np.random.randint(np.prod(arr.shape[:-1]), size=10000))
arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1])[ix] = pattern

# find all instances of the pattern array (ignore partial matches)
loc = np.all(arr==pattern, axis=-1).astype(int)

# test that the found locs are equivalent to the test ixs
locix = np.ravel_multi_index(loc.nonzero(), arr.shape[:-1])
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.sort(ix), np.sort(locix))
# test has been run, the above assert passes
```

Comment: I tried it out, the second one works! Thanks.. but for the first one, it makes partial matches 1 as well, like if it's actually [4,5,6] and you search [4,5,4] it'll be 1 anyways. I think that's because it adds up to 2 (matches out of 3) and that cast to bool makes it 1 as well. I think if you divide the result by 3 as a float then truncate to int and convert to bool it'll be right, but the second one works.

Comment: You were right about the first case. I changed it to something  simpler that should be robust against partial matches.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, let's say that we are looking for all locations where all 3 channels equal 1. This will do the job:

```
np.random.seed(0)
a=np.random.randint(0,2,(3,5,5))
print(a)
np.where((a[0]==1)*(a[1]==1)*(a[2]==1))
```

This outputs

```
[[[0 1 1 0 1]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [1 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 1 1 0 0]]

 [[1 1 1 1 0]
  [1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 0 1 1 0]
  [0 1 0 1 1]
  [1 1 1 0 1]]

 [[0 1 1 1 1]
  [0 1 0 0 1]
  [1 0 1 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 0 0 0]]]

(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 4], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 4, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

And indeed there are 5 coordinates in which all 3 channels equal 1.
If you want to get a more easy to read representation, replace the last row with

```
tuple(zip(*np.where((a[0]==1)*(a[1]==1)*(a[2]==1))))
```

This will output

```
((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 0), (4, 1))
```

which are all the 5 locations where all 3 channels equal 1.

Note that `(a[0]==1)*(a[1]==1)*(a[2]==1)` is just

```
array([[False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]])
```

the boolean representation that you were looking for.

If you want to get any other triplet, say `[143, 255, 0]`, just use `(a[0]==143)*(a[1]==255)*(a[2]==0)`.